# How do I save image from inside application? Or quit application to save image?

Tags: docker

I am completely new to docker containers and very lost.  I am a running application that trains a model and I need to stop the application and/or save the trained state.

Presently, I have a prompt that is like:

root@39392..de2:/app#

This seems to be an application command line.  If I try something like, "$ docker stop", I get a command not found.

How I am supposed to end this and save the image?

Comment: You might look at material like Docker's official [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial that walks through the standard `docker build` sequence.  You usually shouldn't see a container shell prompt like what you quote.

Answer (score 0):

you can create image from container using command

```
docker commit container_name new_image_name
```

you can run container in -d (detach) mode, so you don't need to exit from container all time
`docker run -d`
and after starting container if you want to do any changes you can go to container using `docker exec -it container_id`

Comment: You should almost never run `docker commit`.  It leads to opaque images that you won't be able to reproduce if there's an updated application code, or if there's a security fix in a base image.